# How to create an interface method which when not implemented shows exception code in VB.Net, just like in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have seen in C# that Interfaces when implemented in a class, give methods with an `NotImplementedException` block in them.

This way

```
public interface IDisposable
{
    void Dispose();
}
```

and when implimenting it

```
public class Class1 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now my question

1. Is this only a C# built-in facility and is not available in VB.Net?
2. If No, how can I have this functionality in VB.Net?

Comment: This is more of a Visual Studio feature than something specific to C#.

Comment: @starskythehutch: Then this can be done in VB.Net. Right. How?

Comment: That is just Visual Studio *adding a default template* (or is that ReSharper magic?). It says "HEY, FIX THIS". Nothing in the language itself ..

Comment: If it's not standard functionality, then you'll need to either find a plugin that does it, or create one yourself.

Comment: @starskythehutch: It's not exactly a visual studio feature. The **code generation** when you click *implement interface* is a feature.

Comment: I think you better check out the snippets under **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio N.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring**, maybe you could modify one and it works out like say `MethodStub.Snippet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Visual Studio plug-in like [JustCode](http://www.telerik.com/products/justcode.aspx), which offers such a feature for VB.Net:

```
Interface Foo
    Sub Bar()
End Interface

Class FooBar
    Implements Foo

    Public Sub Bar() Implements Foo.Bar     -+
        ' TODO: Implement this method        +-- these lines are autogenerated
        Throw New NotImplementedException()  |
    End Sub                                 -+

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing C# specific about this. VB.NET supports [Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28e2e18x.aspx) and [`Throw`ing of exceptions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek)

```
Class Class1
    Implements IDisposable

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Disclaimer: I am not a VB.NET coder.

Comment: I think he wants it to create it automatically when he clicks "Implement Interface"

Comment: @starskythehutch Ah, I guess I missed that. Good point. Regardless, here is the code he can copy-and paste in. Sucks to use VB.NET :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart C'mon! VB 10.0 was such an improvement to older versions (goodbye `ByVal` keyword, goodbye `_` abomination) :-)